# Playful reply to a child saying "no"

Tags: phrase-request

In my language, when a child says "oh no!" to complain about something silly, we have a funny phrase to reply to it.

Is there any similar word game in English that happens in this context? Something like, "Dad, I"m hungry / Nice to meet you, Hungry!," but to react a kid who's saying "no" to some decision you've made for the kid's day.

Comment: It's not quite clear what kind of situation you are referring to. You say the child is 'complaining about something silly', then that they are refusing to comply with a decision you have made. What is the sense of the phrase in your own language?

Comment: There are many stock or habitual responses - if, when I was small, I asked for something, e.g. a new toy, candy, etc, and, when my mother refused, I whined and said "But I want it!", my mother used to say "Want will be your master!". Others included 'Don't care was made to care!" and "Don't want to was made to want to!" Such replies could be traditional or unique to a family, locality, or ethnic background. A list could go on forever.

Comment: If I cried, both parents might say "If you don't shut up, I'll give you something to _really_ cry for!". This was not unique to my family. This was the 1950s. I think such attitudes to children are less common these days.